# Using jQuery to Populate Data from More Than One Select Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Anytime a person gets executed, I notify the Judge who put him away.

Recently, we have found there is a problem with people putting down the wrong Executioner. This would not normally be a big deal, but there are some bosses with big families that can make life difficult for the person that performed the execution.

So, the form now needs to be modified to also include an email to the Executioner.

Here are the basics of the webpage:

```
<form method="post">
Person Executed:
<input type="text" name="_jp2code_killed" value="" size="30" />
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="_jp2code_name_original_value" id="_jp2code_name_original_value" value="Web Master" />
<input type="hidden" name="_jp2code_mail_original_value" id="_jp2code_mail_original_value" value="no-reply@jp2code.net" /><br />
Judge:
<select name="Judge" id="Judge">
    <option value="Neal Barton" _jp2code_judge="NBarton@ketknbc.com">Neal Barton</option>
    <option value="Howard Pain" _jp2code_judge="hpain@courtcircuit1.us">Howard Pain</option>
</select>
Executioner:
<select name="Executioner" id="Executioner">
    <option value="Joe Byrd" _jp2code_executioner="jbyrd@walls.tx.us">Joe Byrd</option>
    <option value="Jim Estelle" _jp2code_executioner="jestelle@tdcj.org">Jim Estelle</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<br />
debug:
<input type="text" name="_jp2code_debug" id="_jp2code_debug" size="30" /><br />
</form>
```

With those definitions in place, here is the jQuery (v1.7) that I am trying to get to work:

```
$(function () {
    // Save references to elements
    var objName = $('#_jp2code_name_original_value');
    if (!objName.attr('_jp2code_custom_parameter') ||
                ($.trim(objName.attr('_jp2code_custom_parameter')) == '')) {
        objName.attr('_jp2code_custom_parameter', objName.val());
    }
    var objEmail = $('#_jp2code_mail_original_value');
    if (!objEmail.attr('_jp2code_custom_parameter') ||
                ($.trim(objEmail.attr('_jp2code_custom_parameter')) == '')) {
        objEmail.attr('_jp2code_custom_parameter', objEmail.val());
    }
    $('#Judge').each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () { // Add OnChange EventHandler
            var oItem = $(this); // reference to current element
            var oName = $('#_jp2code_name_original_value'); // Save references to names
            var oEmal = $('#_jp2code_mail_original_value'); // Save references to emails
            if ($.trim(oItem.Val()) != '') {
                oName.val(oName.attr('_jp2code_mail_original_value') + ',Judge');
                oEmal.val(oEmal.attr('_jp2code_mail_original_value') + ',' + $(this).children(':selected').attr('_jp2code_judge'));
            } else {
                oName.val(oName.attr('_jp2code_mail_original_value'));
                oEmal.val(oEmal.attr('_jp2code_mail_original_value'));
            }
            $('#_jp2code_debug_name').val(oName.val());
            $('#_jp2code_debug_emal').val(oEmal.val());
        });
    });
});
```

So, despite my best efforts, a couple of things aren't working:

1. My debug boxes that should be getting the people's names and email addresses is not working. Those debug boxes should always at least include the *Web Master* name and email address, then append the person's name and address when they are selected. I can't seem to get past that.
2. Once that is working, how would I add the logic functioning, then I need to include both names and both email addresses from the select boxes.

Here is where I have been fiddling with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/c5Q2V/

Comment: That's because you're having an error. `.each` is redundant, `.Val` should be `.val`. The debug field should display text now, but I am not sure what you want in the place of where `undefined` appears...

Comment: something like this [http://jsfiddle.net/c5Q2V/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/c5Q2V/1/)?

Comment: @Colandus - do you use anything that pops up a notice when there are errors? The hardest part about me doing jQuery is because all I have to write it with is a dumb text editor.

Comment: @AbrahamUribe, that is what I was trying to start with. Check. Now, how do I get the "Executioner" in the text fields next to the "Web Master" and "Judge"?

Comment: @jp2code Just keep your console open and look out for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/wunC2/1/

I added a custom attribute to my  elements with "Web Master" or the default email address to the HTML:

```
<form method="post">
Person Executed: <input type="text" name="_jp2code_killed" value="" size="30"/>
<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="_jp2code_name_original_value" id="_jp2code_name_original_value" _jp2code_name_original_value="Web Master" />
<input type="hidden" name="_jp2code_mail_original_value" id="_jp2code_mail_original_value" _jp2code_mail_original_value="norsvp@mail.com" /><br/>
Judge:
<select name="Judge" id="Judge">
    <option value="First1 Judge1" _jp2code_judge="judge1@mail.com">First1 Judge1</option>
    <option value="First2 Judge2" _jp2code_judge="judge2@mail.com">First2 Judge2</option>
</select>
Executioner:
<select name="Executioner" id="Executioner">
    <option value="First1 Exec1" _jp2code_executioner="exec1@mail.com">First1 Exec1</option>
    <option value="First2 Exec2" _jp2code_executioner="exec2@mail.com">First2 Exec2</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<br/>
debug: <input type="text" name="_jp2code_debug_name" id="_jp2code_debug_name" size="50" /><br/>
debug: <input type="text" name="_jp2code_debug_emal" id="_jp2code_debug_emal" size="50" /><br/>
</form>
```

For the jQuery, I trimmed it down to a function that was passed to both Select controls, and I had to call the function once so the data would be pre-populated:

```
$(function() {
  function jp2code_get_data() {
    var obj1 = $('#_jp2code_name_original_value');
    var val1 = obj1.attr('_jp2code_name_original_value');
    val1 += ','+$('#Judge').children(':selected').val();
    val1 += ','+$('#Executioner').children(':selected').val();
    var obj2 = $('#_jp2code_mail_original_value');
    var val2 = obj2.attr('_jp2code_mail_original_value');
    val2 += ','+$('#Judge').children(':selected').attr('_jp2code_judge');
    val2 += ','+$('#Executioner').children(':selected').attr('_jp2code_executioner');
    obj1.val(val1);
    obj2.val(val2);
    $('#_jp2code_debug_name').val(obj1.val());
    $('#_jp2code_debug_emal').val(obj2.val());
  }
  $('#Judge, #Executioner').each(function () {
    $(this).change(jp2code_get_data);
  });
  jp2code_get_data();
});
```

This is probably not helpful to everyone, but I like to post the solution if others have the same problem.